# python return a square of #s

Tags: python, return

Good day, I how can I write a function that takes in a number and returns a square filled with the #'s on each side eg if the input is 2  then I must get 2x2 matrics filled with #'s, if the input is 3 I must get 3x3 matrics filled with #s. I am not supposed to use a print function but return, the code below prints out the correct output, but I do not want to use print I want to return, I do not want any GUI just an output

```
def square(number):
    for i in range(1,number+1):
        #print(i)
        for j in range(1, number ):
            #print(j)
            o=('#'*number)
        print(o)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some little changes will do. Just build a string of what you are printing and return it in the end:

```
def square(number):
    S = ""
    for _ in range(number):
        s += "#" * number + "\n"  # print adds the line break implicitly
    return s
```

You can simplify that, of course:

```
def square(number):
    return "\n".join("#" * number for _ in range(number))
```

Now you can print the value returned by your function:

```
>>> print(square(5))
#####
#####
#####
#####
#####
```

Comment: is there a way I can do it without using the print function? i.e buy just calling the function only not print(square(5)

Comment: In the interactive interpreter, you can just call `square(5)`, and see some representation of the returned str. But in real life, if you want something written to the console, you have to use `print` (or something similar, e.g. `sys.stdout.write`)

Comment: I want an output, not a GUI interaction,